# Facebook sharer : image just created

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, nginx, share, preview

I'm working on an application that creates an avatar, creates an image on server from the avatar base64, then show a share button for Facebook, to share that avatar, just created.

The custom share button calls the current page with an additionnal URL parameter containing the avatar's filename. When this parameter is set (when Facebook crawls it with the share URL), I create the og tags in the head, with the path of the image given in the URL parameter.

**No problem with that, everything is ok.**

But the problem is : the dialog with the preview doesn't show the avatar, whereas it **IS** created on the server ! **I have to open the dialog several times to see the avatar.** *(open, no avatar, cancel... open, no avatar, cancel... open, ah ! the avatar, finally !).*

Same problem with the Facebook URL Debugger. First time, it doesn't find the avatar (whereas it exists), second or third time, ok it finds it.

As the avatar is created, shouldn't the preview show the avatar ? Does the server need some time after creating the image to "enable" it ? (server is a nginx)

[image]

Comment: This is more likely not a problem with the dynamic image creation itself, but with the specific URL with the parameter not having been crawled before. And the easy workaround for that is to [specify the image _dimensions_ via OG meta tags as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361572/1427878).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making an AJAX request force Facebook to update the image from their end when the page loads that contains your share link:

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: 'http://www.website.com/pagetoscrape',
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        // or you could call the dialog box at this point
    }
);
```

Comment: I've tried to call that just before opening the sharing dialog, but my console says : **XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph.facebook.com/. The request was redirected to a URL ('about:blank') which has a disallowed scheme for cross-origin requests.**

When calling during Facebook crawling, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem (but no error, the preview works like before : without the avatar).

Comment: Strange, I just ran it in the console and it works fine.  and it returns JSON as the response, not about:blank

Answer (score 0):

I ran to this error yesterday this is my attempt

```
$.post(
    'https://graph.facebook.com',
    {
        id: current+"/share/"+id,
        scrape: true
    },
    function(response){
        //alert('scrap')
        setTimeout(function(){
          $("#facebook").attr("href",url_facebook ); 
        }, 800)
       ;
    }
);
```

Facebook takes a little time to get the information, so thats why I use the setTimeOut, to give a little break for facebook to catch the information