# Facebook Does Not Grab Proper og:Image On Initial Share

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have Wordpress site with a small bit of php code which creates the OpenGraph tags for each post. Unfortunately the Featured image (og:image) is not grabbed by Facebook when I copy the URL into a new FB post.

Just to clarify the flow of events:

1. My users create a Wordpress post.
2. Then someone shares it on Facebook by copying the link into a FB post. Facebook displays the proper text, but grabs the wrong og:image.
3. I go to the object debugger and test the Wordpress post. It shows no errors and all the correct og tags (including the correct og:image) but displays the default (wrong) image for the site in its thumbnail!
4. Then if I click the Scrape New button, the proper thumbnail (matching the og:image tag) appears.
5. Now if a user shares the same Wordpress post in Facebook, FB -does- display the proper og:image in the FB post.

So initially the -default- image is being grabbed, but not the Featured image (ie. the post_thumbnail() in Wordpress parlance. However, if I open the 'Object Debugger For Facebook' and get a new scrape for the page, the correct image always appears. This has gotten tedious.

The maddening thing is that if I look in the Object Debugger for the initial scrape, although the Default Image is displayed (which is incorrect) if I look at the stats, the og:image tag Facebook says it sees is -correct-. So it's -says- it scraped the correct image, but is displaying the incorrect image!

The only error I ever see in the Object Debugger is that "the image may be too small. Images must be at least 200x200..."... which is not true. The image is always at -least- 300 x 209.

I've checked that the code in the page header generates properly.

I am not using a caching plug-in or a CDN.

So: How can I insure that FB always grabs the correct og:image WITHOUT having to open the object debugger and Scrape New.

Again: I've seen similar (old) questions here where the 'answer' was to run a new scrape for every post. Well, that just isn't going to fly with my users. We need a way to insure that a new post shows the correct og:image without having to do any extra work.

```
function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;
    if ( !is_singular()) //if it is not a post or a page
        return;

//echo '<meta property="fb:admins" content="YOUR USER ID"/>';

  echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
  echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
  echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
  echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="example site"/>';
  echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true). '"/>';

if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) { //the post does not have featured image, use a default image
    $default_image="http://jchmusic.com/images/default-250.jpg"; //replace this with a default image on your server or an image in your media library
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
}
else{
    $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
    echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:image:width" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[1] ) . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:image:height" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[2] ) . '"/>';      

}
echo "";
}
 add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
  /* Facebook ends *************/
```

Comment: I'd say that your logic is backwards (for the purpose of testing, at the very least).. Generally you want to check if something exists, else default, not default if it doesn't exist. There could be a myriad of logic errors you don't know about right now.

Comment: My users create a Wordpress post. Then someone shares it on FB... and FB grabs the wrong og:image. I go to the object debugger and it shows no errors AND the correct og:image tag what could I be doing wrong. Since clicking the Scrape New button fixes the issue, there must be -something- in the initial page rendering that prevents FB from scraping the proper image initially. I'd like to know what that is. Again: the object debugger shows no errors.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the image dimensions via meta tags as well? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361572/1427878

Comment: I did try adding the og: image dimensions (see updated question). Did not help. Still requires a trip through the URL Debugger.

Comment: What does the debug tool show for a fresh URL after you shared it, but before you triggered a re-scrape? Everything as it should be, especially in regard to og:url/canonical/redirects?

Comment: The only issues the object debugger ever shows me are 1 or 2 'Warnings' 
"og:image could not be downloaded or is too small" and "Share App ID Missing" In the case of the image size, this is bogus: the images  are always greater than the minimum 200x200. As far as the Share App ID, whether or not I use it makes no difference---again: in the info it shows the correct og:image url but the actual image displayed is always the 'default'

Comment: Also, the fetched URL and the canonical url always match.

Comment: While your users are making the post, do they ever preview the page? I have heard that at that moment, FB will scrape the post already and whatever is in og:image at that time, is taken as the image. So try and make a post without previewing. Do you then also have the problem?

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't help. So far the only thing that 'fixes' the problem is: a) make the FB post. b) Delete FB post. c) Re-post same post. The 2nd post will show the correct image.