# FaceBook - Javascript API Share is pulling safe_image instead of og:image

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm have a strange issue with the FaceBook Javascrip API.  When i use the API to invoke a Share popup, the window rendered by FaceBook is using an image it should never use.

When I use Facebook's Sharing Debugger I get the following:
[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.investx.com%2Fdeals%2Fspotify

When I go to my website (www.investx.com/deals or www.investx.com/deals/spotify) and click the facebook share it is showing me:

[image]

When inspecting the share popup I see that FaceBook is pulling a weird image from a blog reference:

[image]

Here is the meta tags for my page:

```
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.investx.com/deals/spotify" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Spotify 4 - OFFERING | Company Snapshot" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="InvestX.Platform.Model.DealManagement.Deal?.DealCardForCurrentUser?.ShortDescription" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.investx.com/SpotifyLogoTransparent.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:url"  content="https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.investx.com/SpotifyLogoTransparent.png" />
```

Comment: After a re-scrape, debug tool currently shows warnings: _“Image Unavailable - Provided og:image, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.investx.com/SpotifyLogoTransparent.png` could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb or your server was too slow to respond.”_

Comment: And after scraping that URL (of the image itself) once, the warning for the main document is gone.

Comment: Facebook seems to lag on the first scrape, but after that, the developer tools show the proper result. Just their JavaScript SDK isn't pulling the right image.

Comment: Try and see if specifying the image dimensions as well via OG tags helps, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361572/1427878

Comment: @CBroe Tried that, no beans. It's quite weird. I've been seeing this happen a lot with the facebook JS API on multiple sites, so it's most likely something they've done.