# Facebook send dialog is too slow to load images on new pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-share

I am trying to implement a service. Lets say I want to let my users create their page and then share it on Facebook right away.

I tried to use Facebook send dialog. It works, but it can't load images since it is not scraped yet. If I go and scrape the url manually and then try to share it it will work just fine but I need it to work real time for my users.

What shall I do?

---

This is not a duplicate as people said. The solutions was to add og tags for width and height like

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

Comment: see the other thread, the accepted answer is exactly what you need. you can do a post request to the api to scrape new pages/urls.

Comment: Specifying width and height of the image should also work, http://stackoverflow.com/a/30361572/1427878

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the solution. it works

Comment: @luschn IT was not a duplicate. I didn't ask how to scrape it. The solution was adding image width and height to og tags

Comment: "it can't load images since it is not scraped yet" - actually, you did ask for that. CBroes solution is better (and easier) though.