# on facebook share image is not appearing for the first time though meta has og image height and width

Tags: facebook, share

I have the below tags in my facebook share page but the image is not appearing for the first time in my share dialogue box.

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxx" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="xxxx" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://web.dailyhunt.in/buzz/video/english/fresh/but-gabriel-boschilia-24-as-monaco-fc-lorient-4-0-2016-17-frsh-hi-139074" />
<meta property="og:title" content="But Gabriel BOSCHILIA (24') / AS Monaco - FC Lorient (4-0) -  / 2016-17" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://tcdn.newshunt.com/images/items/1/3/9/0/74/139074_share.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="400" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />
```

Search for solution and found [Facebook ignoring OG image on first share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356716/facebook-ignoring-og-image-on-first-share).

But I have already added those tags. Please suggest where am I wrong.

Comment: that is not a proper format for the og image. have you tried with a correct one? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images

Comment: yes I have tried with  200 x 200 and still no difference. For the first time the image isn't coming

Comment: +1 Were you ever able to resolve this? I am running into the same issue, and my og tags look almost identical to yours. Very frustrating!

Comment: no improvement. for the first time the image is not loading and the fb debugger is showing this warning : "The provided 'og:image' properties are not yet available because new images are processed asynchronously. To ensure shares of new URLs include an image, specify the dimensions using 'og:image:width' and 'og:image:height' tags."

Comment: I can confirm the problem with first shares not showing images, even if all og-tags are present.